# Assignment / modification of values in an indexed subframe in Pandas

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, variable-assignment

The documentation for indexing has few examples of assignment of a non-scalar right hand side.

In this case, I want to modify a subset of my dataframe, and what I did prior to v.13 no longer works.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *

data = {'me':list('rttti'),'foo': list('aaade'), 'bar': arange(5)*1.34+2, 'bar2': arange(5)*-.34+2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('me')

print df

df.loc['r',['bar','bar2']]*=2.0
print df
df.loc['t','bar']*=2.5
# Above fails: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and valuewhen setting with an iterable
print df
df.loc['t',['bar','bar2']]*=2.0
# Above fails: *** InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
print df
```

I want to be able to assign a matrix of values to a matrix of locations using loc or, in this simplifed case, I just want to modify them by some simple operation like multiplication.

The first modification works (the index value is unique), and the others do not, though they give different errors.

Comment: using a non-unique index is NOT recommended and in general assignment is very tricky; use a multi-index or reset before assigning. any reason you really want to do this? That said this might be a bug.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6541

Comment: Multi-index: Because it seems that there are issues with this kind of block-assignments using multi-indices which are either poorly documented or too complex for me.  And Reset: I cannot figure out how to do that (cleanly) either, after lots of hacking around. I thought I was keeping things simple, and various places say to just assign a block of values into your df and all will be well.  (This is all making me feel pretty dumb!)

Comment: try ``df.reset_index()``; multi-index assignement will be a bit easier in 0.14. But you have to think of *why* you are doing things this way. Assignment is often not a good solution; creating a new frame is quite cheap and often much better to use vectorized methods.

Comment: @Jeff. Oh; that's fine. How would I create a new frame with the change?

Comment: this all works on 0.16.2, give a try with that