# Adding data to Pandas Dataframe from a CSV file causing Value Errors

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I am trying to add an `int` to an existing value in a `Pandas` `DataFrame` with

```
>>> df.ix['index 5','Total Dollars'] += 10
```

I get the error: 
`ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`.

I think the error comes from the `datatype` as gotten from:

```
>>> print type(df.ix['index 5','Total Dollars'] 
int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The dataframe is populated via CSV file. I tried loading the database from another CSV file:

```
>>> print type(df.ix['index 5','Total Dollars']
int64
```

What could be causing this difference in type?

Comment: Can you provide a data sample for us to reproduce your error? SO recommends a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from askers. You might get better response.

Comment: A couple thoughts:  use `df.info()` to check the type of entire columns (rather than individual elements).  Generally speaking, you'll want to see that these are ints and floats.  You shouldn't see columns as objects unless they contain strings.  When you read in a CSV, pandas will generally make the correct type choices, but not always, and you may need to adjust this during or after reading in the CSV.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug for some earlier `pandas` versions, fixed at least with `0.16.2` if not earlier as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178642/assignment-modification-of-values-in-an-indexed-subframe-in-pandas) and [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6541).

With `0.17.1`, this works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[5], columns=['Total Dollars'], index=['index 5'])

         Total Dollars
index 5              5

df.ix['index 5', 'Total Dollars'] += 10

         Total Dollars
index 5             15
```